# How to analyze all traces in a graph analyzed with minimum spanning trees?

Tags: python, scipy, minimum-spanning-tree

The Minimum Spanning Tree algorithm (MST) allows to find the shortest possible connexion for all nodes. In Python, Scipy provides a package to analyze MST. I want to find a way to get the main traces based on the connexions. In the example underneath, there is a trace at dest2-dest4-dest1 and another one at source-dest4-dest3 (other combination of traces are possible as well).

[image]

```
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import minimum_spanning_tree
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

The example has the following coordinate points for source and destinations

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2, 2], [30, 2], [2, 30], [25, 25], [14,10]], columns=['xcord', 'ycord'], index=['source', 'dest1', 'dest2', 'dest3', 'dest4'])
```

A distance matrix and minimum spanning tree with resulting distances can be computed.

```
dm = pd.DataFrame(distance_matrix(df.values, df.values), index=df.index, columns=df.index)

mst = minimum_spanning_tree(dm)

arr_distances = mst.toarray()
```

This gives the following array.

```
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [14.4222051 , 17.88854382, 23.32380758, 18.60107524,  0.        ]])
```

Which means, distance source-dest4 = 14.42, dest1-dest4 = 17.89, dest2-dest4 = 23.32 and dest3-dest4 = 18.60.

How can one capture the available main trace(s) expressed in a list or numpy.array like ['source', 'dest4', 'dest3'] and ['dest2', 'dest4', 'dest1'] ? This should work for any configuration of input coordinates.

So far I have tried to get the main connexions using `np.argwhere(arr_distances > 0)`, but somehow it is difficult to get them as aforementioned traces in different lists or sublists.

It would be good if the solution were in Python, but any other package than Scipy is welcome. Thank you very much in advance for your help!